# How to fix error not valid identifier?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

every time i open a bash session i am having the following error message in the terminal.

```
bash: export: `Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/mnt/c/Users/Myusername/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/Myusername/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft': not a valid identifier

bash: export: `Code/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/root/go/bin': not a valid identifier
```

I am new to linux and bash, i don't really understand what is wrong here.
Can someone help me fix this, please?

Comment: Did you recently try to add a PATH to one of your shell startup files?

Comment: yes i did a lot of that lately, got a new laptop, so i had to set environments variable here and there. Last one was golan, which makes sense but for the 1st line of error i am totally lost, can you help with that? @steeldriver

Comment: Without seeing the contents of the file(s) you edited (~/.bashrc ? ~/.bash_profile ?) it's hard to help - most likely you made a mistake with whitespace and/or quoting

Comment: ... as well, if you're using WSL please make that clear either in the body of the question or by adding the [windows-subsystem-for-linux tag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux)

Comment: i run ~/.bash_profile, i get no such file in directory

Comment: Don't cross-post the same question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/722389/330217 https://askubuntu.com/q/1437006/1186757 https://stackoverflow.com/q/74191044/10622916

Comment: I have been stuck on this for a couple of days, not getting answers here I thought it was the wrong community.  Should I delete or flag it as related? @Bodo